# Div parent doesn't auto height with content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with background of a div.

```
<div class='new-vertical-slider'>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="news-contenedor-li bg-gray">
                    <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 news-day bg-gray'><h3>19</h3></div>
                    <div class='col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9'>
                        <a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-To-Expand-Collapse-Input-Field-Expandable-Input.html">Expandable Input</a>
                        <p>Expandable Input is a minimal jQuery plugin to smoothly expand the width of a input filed when focused/clicked and collapse it when lose focus.</p>                      
                    </div>  
                    <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Jmpoj3p.jpg" alt="Expandable Input" /></div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 news-day bg-orange' ><h3>24</h3></div>
                <div class='col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9'>    
                    <a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-To-Expand-Collapse-Input-Field-Expandable-Input.html">Expandable Input</a>
                    <p>Expandable Input is a minimal jQuery plugin to smoothly expand the width of a input filed when focused/clicked and collapse it when lose focus.</p>
                </div>  
                <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2'><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Jmpoj3p.jpg" alt="Expandable Input" /></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 news-day bg-orange'><h3>28</h3></div>
                <div class='col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9'>
                    <a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-To-Expand-Collapse-Input-Field-Expandable-Input.html">Expandable Input</a>
                    <p>Expandable Input is a minimal jQuery plugin to smoothly expand the width of a input filed when focused/clicked and collapse it when lose focus.</p>
                </div>  
                <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2'><img class='pull-right' src="http://i.imgur.com/Jmpoj3p.jpg" alt="Expandable Input" /></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 news-day bg-gray-strong'><h3>31</h3></div>
                <div class='col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9'>
                    <a href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-To-Expand-Collapse-Input-Field-Expandable-Input.html">Expandable Input</a>
                    <p>Expandable Input is a minimal jQuery plugin to smoothly expand the width of a input filed when focused/clicked and collapse it when lose focus.</p>
                </div>  
                <div class='col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2'><img class='pull-right' src="http://i.imgur.com/Jmpoj3p.jpg" alt="Expandable Input" /></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is CSS

```
    .new-vertical-slider {
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.new-vertical-slider ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.new-vertical-slider li {
    border: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.new-vertical-slider li:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}


.new-vertical-slider li:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}


.new-vertical-slider li a {
    color: #4d4d4d;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.new-vertical-slider li a:hover {
    color:  #fc8020;
}

.new-vertical-slider img {
    width: 100%;
}

.new-vertical-slider a {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #06f;
}

.new-vertical-slider p {
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.news-title {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.news-day {
    color: white;
    font-style: bold;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    font-family: "Arial Black";
}

.news-contenedor-li {
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.bg-orange {
    background: #fc8020;
}
.bg-gray-strong {
    background: #cccccc;
}
.bg-gray {
    background: #eaeaea;
}
.bg-orange-light{
    background: #fcf2ea;
}
.hr-news-top {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.hr-news-bottom {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

I'm using EasyTicker (jQuery plugin) for slide the news, but I have a problem with height. As you can see in the image, the div height doesn't adjust to the content of the div.

[image: First row background]

Comment: can you please add the JavaScript and jQuery too to the fiddle I just created?

Comment: the problem isn't the div but the image size, the div is getting bigger because the image is too big

Comment: Now i dont care if image is a little big (as u can see in my image), I want to know how to force parent div height adjust the content and print background color well.

Comment: I put your source in [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/a5oos63g/), but it doesn't look like your screenshot. Do you have more CSS somewhere? Anyway, apart from that, either @Jeremy is correct, or you have not described the problem clearly enough.

Comment: in the divs that have a background colours try putting this (in css): background-size: 100% 100%;

Comment: there is something wrong in the code that is generating your news thingies, the first div i've been able to fix in this fiddle (in your css i changed teh background css class bg-gray): but I doubt you are manually writing your html, or if you do, you are doing it wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/a5oos63g/1/

Comment: I use, bootstrap, the css asociated to this code is posted.

Answer (score 1):

On `.new-vertical-slider` class add this css `overflow: auto` :

```
.new-vertical-slider {
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And do it for other parent divs and remove `height:100%;`. Sorry I have no time to write it all.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using display: inline-block on .news-contenedor-li

```
.news-contenedor-li {
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
```

}

[image: Result image]